# How to change splash screen in sencha touch cordova app

Tags: cordova, extjs, splash-screen

I have created an app in sencha touch cordova. I have successfully changed the app icon using following code in the config.xml file in the cordova folder but splash screen is not changing for windows 8.1  phone.

```
<platform name="wp8">
    <icon src="www/resources/icons/icon.png"/>
    <splash src="www/resources/startup/splash.png"/>
</platform>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="7000" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried splash screen with specific height and width attributes which worked for me.

Ex :

```
<platform name="wp8">
    <icon src="www/resources/startup/Icon.png"/>
    <splash height="1280" src="www/resources/startup/Splash-768x1280.png" width="768"/>
</platform>
```

For more info on splashscreen configuration refer : 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref_images.md.html

Comment: thanks it working fine. but splash screen not displaying properly. It disappeared  with in one second. I want to display it for 7-8 second. Can you please tell the solution.

Comment: Try this:

SplashScreenDelay (number in milliseconds): The amount of time the splash screen image displays.
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/> or use org.apache.cordova.splashscreen plugin.